# No definite article after “by”

Tags: prepositions, definite-articles

Can I avoid using “the” in the phrase “by artist John Smith,” as opposed to “by the artist John Smith.” If the phrase is on a title section it reads somewhat pompous, but I need to provide a justification for it.

Comment: I might buy the book which had 'by the artist John Smith' rather than the one containing 'by artist John Smith', but neither is ungrammatical.

Comment: You can justify it by thinking of ‘‘artist’’ as a title.  You wouldn’t think twice about saying “by Dr. John Smith” or “by Governor John Smith”.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate...

Comment: Were link-only answers acceptable in 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Using a noun with no definite article before a proper name is called a [*false title*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title), functioning the same way as a genuine title such as Professor Smith, Chairman Smith, etc. A stylistic invention of American journalism in the late nineteenth century, such false titles were originally capitalized just as real ones.

While the capitalization was later dropped, the practice has not been without [controversy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title#Controversy), and even those who do not object to it per se may still consider it too journalistic for other contexts.

Except for various tabloids, the usage has only slowly gained a foothold in [Britain,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title#British_usage) with such publications as the *Guardian* and the *Economist* proscribing it.

Since I am unsure what you mean by "title section" or who your intended readership might be, I can't advise you further. Americans would not likely give it a second thought, while Britons might sense its American provenance.